How to allow HTTPS on Elastic Beanstalk application
I have deployed my React Frontend/Client using AWS Amplify. Which is automatically adding SSL to teh production branch URL
and my Backend/API was deployed using AWS ElasticBeans
Now the problem is, I am unable to make any API/HTTP request to my server from client because of the error,

Mixed Content: The page at 'My HTTPS Ampify URL here' was loaded over
HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'My HTTP
Beanstalk here’. This request has been blocked; the content must be
served over HTTPS.

How can I configure AWS Beanstalk to be HTTPS?
Honestly I read a lot of solutions about it on the internet,

Created a SSL Certificate using Amazon Certificate Manager
Added an Application Load Balancer on my Beanstalk
Added a Listener port 443, adding the Certificate created on step 1

and after that, I'm receiving 502 Bad Gateway when trying to reach my backend on HTTPS
Tried some solutions that I saw

Make API request to HTTP endpoint from AWS Amplify deployed HTTPS (SSL) Client
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html


From your description I think you might have missed adding a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.
If that is the case you need to create an additional listener that listens for HTTP request and redirects them to HTTPS.
Here is a link explaining in detail
